# Is it possible to output a VPC peering connection request id using CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I wrote a CloudFormation template, which among other stuff also creates a VPC peering connection.

If you are familiar with VPC peerings then you know that after the creation, a request is created and waiting for approval.

I'd like to add to the outputs portion of the CloudFormation template the VPC peering connection request id.

Is that possible? I couldn't find the way...

Edit:

This is the relevant portion of the template:

```
"Resources" : {
  "VPC": {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC",
    "Description" : "Choose which VPC the security groups should be deployed to",
    "Properties" : {
      "CidrBlock" : "172.51.0.0/16",
      "EnableDnsSupport" : "true",
      "EnableDnsHostnames" : "true",
      "InstanceTenancy" : "default"
    }
  },

  "VPCPeering" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection",
    "Properties" : {
      "PeerVpcId" : "vpc-2XXXXXb",
      "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }
    }
  },
```

I'm using Jenkins with the CloudFormation plugin to issue the creation of a new stack.

I want the new stack to automatically create peering between the VPC that the stack creates and the existing management VPC.

My plan was to issue the creation through the template, and then once the creation completes, I intended to use AWS Cli (from Jenkins) to accept the peering request and since this step requires me to know the vpc peering request id, then I wanted to output it using the `"Outputs" : {}` section of the template.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-peering-vpc-different-account/) describes the workaround

"This article describes a procedure that allows a requester_account to both request and approve the peering connection. To do so, the peer_account must create a cross-account role that the requester_account can use to accept the peering request..."

Comment: Both VPC are on the same account... can it still be possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, see the AWS documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html). An example of what isn't working for you would help.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: I just used CloudFormation to create a stack using the example template from the link above, which creates a VPC to VPC peer (pcx-* resource), within the same account. With no need to record or manipulate VPCIDs outside of CloudFormation. If one of the VPCs already exists then just refer to the VPCID in the peering request. So I still don't understand your issue. 

I suggest that you cut Jenkins out of the loop and get your cf template working natively; note there are a number of restrictions for peering such as not overlapping ID addresses, and you still need a route to make it work, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. CloudFormation only supports VPC Peering where peering is automatically approved (i.e. within the same account) or where you specify a role you can assume to automatically approve the peer.